# Creating WebStorm 2016 live template with restricted list of inputs

Tags: webstorm

While experimenting with Live Templates in WebStorm I found it impossible to create a live template which will give a restricted list of suggestions for a input variable:

For example:

```
console.$logTypes$("$message$");
```

`$logTypes$` - can it be restricted to a list ['log', 'info', ...] ?

Comment: There are `enum()` functionality ([more here in docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/live-template-variables.html?search=live%20te#predefined_functions)) which in theory should do what you are asking .. bu tit's more for strings and not actual methods. You better have separate live templates for each log type (e.g. `cl` for `console.log()`, `ce` for `console.error()` etc -- abbreviations can be quite different -- e.g. `c.l` .. or `conl`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tnx LazyOne, I have found a solution using the enum(...) template expression.

Example:

enum("log","info")